# How to drop down and display this menu?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to load this menu on my page, the urls and the options I get from a tables of a database, only that once loaded the menu, it seems that this is static and not dynamic.

I was thinking of using Jquery, to use the menu classes and to load them after the PHP script is executed

Also I do not know how to make this submenu load for each submenu. 
Since the loop generates a list of suboptions and should have for each list of options this instruction:

> `<ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="products"></ul>`

and I do not know where in the loop to place it.

For example:

```
 <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="products">


                <li class="active"><a href="#">CSS3 Animation</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">General</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Buttons</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tabs & Accordions</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Typography</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">FontAwesome</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Slider</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Panels</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Widgets</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Bootstrap Model</a></li>
            </ul>
```

any ideas?

This is the code:

```
<div class="nav-side-menu"> 
    <div class="brand">Example</div>
    <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x toggle-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-content"></i> 
    <div class="menu-list"> 
        <ul id="menu-content" class="menu-content collapse out"> 

            <li ><a  href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-lg"></i> Inicio</a> </li>

            <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="products">
                <?php
                $rs = opcionesUsuario($usuario);
                $subopcion_ant = 1;
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
                    $url = $row['href'];
                    $caption = $row['caption'];
                    $subopcion = $row['subopcion'];
                    //writeInLog($row['caption']);
                    if ($url <> "") {
                        if (strpos($url, '?') === false) {
                            echo'<li class = "active" ><a href="' . $url . '?usuario=' . $usuario . '">' . $caption . '</a></li></ul>';
                        } else {
                            echo '<li class="active"><a  href="' . $url . '?usuario=' . $usuario . '">' . $caption . '</a></li></ul>';
                        }
                    }//fin de if
                    else {
                        if ($subopcion_ant == 1) {
                            echo '<li data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#products" class="collapsed active">
                                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i> ' . $caption . ' <span class="arrow"></span></a></li>';
                        }
                    }//Fin de else
                    $subopcion_ant = $subopcion;
                } //end of while
                ?>
            </ul> 
    </div>
</div>
```

pd: menuhttps://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/responsive-navigation-menu

Comment: By using any of the [`mysql_*()`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) functions you should be aware that **if** the server updates their software **your code will break** immediately as those function are removed. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. It has native support against [SQL injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) by using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: `<ul><li></li><ul>...`: You can't have a `<ul>` element as a direct child of another `<ul>`. You need an *open* `<li>` element in between.